# Absolute continuity of infinite product of probability measures

Tags: pr.probability, real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $(A_i,\mathcal{B}_i,\mu_i)$ for $i=1,2,\ldots$ be a sequence of probability spaces. Let $\nu_i$ be another sequence of probability measures on the same underlying measurable spaces. Assume that $\mu_i\ll \nu_i$ for any $i$. Under what conditions can we deduce that $\prod_i \mu_i \ll \prod_i \nu_i$?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is described by [Kakutani's theorem on product measures](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=23331). There is a very detailed exposition in Chapter III, Section 9 of Shiryaev's [Probability](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1368405).